# How to move a Character (in sed?)

Tags: linux, sed

I got a csv-file with semicolons within some words instead of between
eg:
wor;d
How can i recognize all semicolons between to characters and move them to the right until no semicolons are between 2 characters?

Comment: Could You please show sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might work for you:

```
sed -r 's/(\w);(\w+\b)/\1\2;/g' filename
```

If you want to save the changes to the file in-place, you can say:

```
sed -i -r 's/(\w);(\w+\b)/\1\2;/g' filename
```

---

If you have words like `;word` that need to be modified to `word;`, you could say:

```
sed -r 's/(\w?);(\w+\b)/\1\2;/g' filename
```